# Run Linux Command inside Docker Container via command line

Tags: bash, docker, unix, kubernetes

I have this command

```
clear; sudo kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pods | grep 'app' | cut -d ' ' -f 1) ash
```

I will land here

```
/src #
```

I want to also run a command `ls`

```
/src # ls                                                                                           
Procfile             composer.lock        phpunit.xml          server.php                           
app                  config               public               storage                              
artisan              database             resources            tests                                
benu.code-workspace  heroku.sh            routes               vendor                               
bootstrap            package-lock.json    run.sh               webpack.mix.js                       
composer.json        package.json         scripts                                                   
/src #
```

I've tried

```
clear; sudo kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pods | grep 'app' | cut -d ' ' -f 1) ash echo "ls"
```

and

```
clear; sudo kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pods | grep 'app' | cut -d ' ' -f 1) echo "ls"
```

Please correct me

Comment: Don't use `-t` if you want the output directed to your command line (and not the container's TTY).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run the command, you want `kubectl exec -it $podname ls`. If you put `echo "ls"` then that is the command which run, i.e. print "ls".